# In C, Fastest way to find and count specific values in binary file of Integers?

Tags: c, find, binaryfiles

I have a binary file which stores multiple blocks of int32 values. Each block starts with the value 999999999, e.g.

999999999
1
5
6
10
2
999999999
4
3
5
8
0
999999999
etc..

Can anyone suggest the fastest way to count the number of 999999999 in the binary file?  I can of course iterate with a for loop and count these values but I assume it is not the best approach.  The reason I want to do this is to pre-allocate an 2D array.

Thanks

Comment: Are there always 5 values between them as in your example? If not, you'll need to know more than just the number of `999999999` values to be able to define or allocate a 2-D array. If yes, you can compute it from the file size.

Comment: Sound spretty much like the only approach. Besides, how you do the file I/O will totally dominate the running time. The actual counting will probably be less than 1% of the overall.

Comment: Memory mapping the file *might* be faster than using i/o functions.

Comment: The number of values between 999999999 is NOT constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the block delimiter codes can appear anywhere throughout the file, you have to read and process the whole file.  Supposing that the program doesn't do something absurd, the cost of the I/O involved will dominate the overall cost of the overall program.

> I can of course iterate with a for loop and count these values but I assume it is not the best approach.

Why wouldn't it be the best approach?  The details matter, of course, but you have to compare each 4-byte chunk, interpreted as the representation of an `int32_t`, with the value 999999999.  That's an inherently iterative process, and it can be well represented via a `for`, `while`, or `do` loop.  I would write it something like this:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define BLOCK_HEADER 999999999

FILE *input = fopen(the_file_name);
int32_t numbers[BUFFER_SIZE];
size_t num_blocks = 0;
size_t count;

for (count = fread(numbers, 4, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
        count > 0;
        count = fread(numbers, 4, BUFFER_SIZE, input)) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == BLOCK_HEADER) num_blocks++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is similar to my current implementation but because I'm kind of new to C I assumed there might be a search/find function optimized for speed.  Thanks everyone for assistance!